# Enumerate and add in a column of the select - Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, enumerate, line-numbers

I need to enumerate my lines in a column of the select by a type. For example, I have three types which can be "RR", "RJ" and "RA", every time that a type "RR" appears I have to sum 3 and the other ones I have to sum only 1, creating a sequence like:

Type     Number 
RR         3
RR         6
RJ         7
RR        10
RJ        11
RA        12
RR        15

I have other fields in the select, so I used the ROW_NUMBER() function with all my order by fields, something like:

```
select
   number,
   [...]
   type,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by number, type [...] )*3 as sequence
from
   my_table
order by number, type [...]
```

I also tried to use a case statement, but it doesn't aggregate the values.

Is it possible to do? I'm trying to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, but i can't get the result, only three by three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SUM`:

```
select
   number,
   [...]
   type,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'RR' THEN 3 ELSE 1 END) 
       OVER (order by number, type [...] ) as sequence
from my_table
order by number, type [...]
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/UJQN12774)**

Comment: Thank you so much! I had tried with the sum, but I didn't use the "OVER (ORDER ..." clause. I also didn't know this "rextester", it's awesome!